# disabling functools.cache for tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, pytest, python-decorators

I'm using the `@cache` decorator in my methods:

```py
class Configuration:

    @classmethod
    @property
    @cache
    def whitelist_sections(cls) -> Set[int]:
        whitelist_sections: Set[int] = set()
        whitelist: str = os.getenv("WHITELIST_SECTIONS", "")
        try:
            whitelist_sections = eval("{" + whitelist + "}")
        except ValueError:
            return whitelist_sections
        return whitelist_sections
```

I want to test the method above, here are my efforts:

```py
def test_whitelist_sections():
    section_id = 8765432
    env_var_mock = mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"WHITELIST_SECTIONS": str(section_id)})
    env_var_mock.start()
    whitelist_sections = Configuration.whitelist_sections
    env_var_mock.stop()
    assert whitelist_sections == {section_id}


def test_whitelist_multiple_sections():
    section_id_1 = 8765432
    section_id_2 = 1234567
    env_var_mock = mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"WHITELIST_SECTIONS": f"{section_id_1},{section_id_2}"})
    env_var_mock.start()
    whitelist_sections = Configuration.whitelist_sections
    env_var_mock.stop()
    assert whitelist_sections == {section_id_1, section_id_2}


def test_whitelist_sections_empty():
    env_var_mock = mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"WHITELIST_SECTIONS": ""})
    env_var_mock.start()
    whitelist_sections = Configuration.whitelist_sections
    env_var_mock.stop()
    assert whitelist_sections == {}
```

The problem is the cache which doesn't allow me to test different scenarios. How can I mock the `@cache` decorator?

I tried this approach but it didn't work:

```py
cache_mock = mock.patch("functools.cache", lambda func: func)
```

**EDIT:** tried this approach:

```py
def mock_cache(function):
    return function()


def test_whitelist_sections():
    section_id = 8765432
    env_var_mock = mock.patch.dict(os.environ, {"WHITELIST_SECTIONS": str(section_id)})
    env_var_mock.start()
    cache_mock = mock.patch("my_module.configuration.cache", mock_cache)
    cache_mock.start()
    whitelist_sections = Configuration.whitelist_sections
    cache_mock.stop()
    env_var_mock.stop()
    assert whitelist_sections == {section_id}
```

Running in debug mode I can see that the decorator was replaced by `mock_cache` but running all together with `pytest` still yield the same error for two (out of free) tests - only first one work

**EDIT2:** note that that's a static method (`@classmethod`)

Comment: You need to patch `cache` within the scope of the module that you're testing, not within the scope of `functools` -- i.e. you want to patch `configuration.cache` or whatever the name of your module is.

Comment: @Samwise I did it like that: `my_module.configuration.cache = Mock(return_value=lambda func: func)`. Running in debugger it seems ok (`@cache` is `Mock`) but running all test via pytest still ignore that :(

Comment: The `patch` call is the right way to do it, just use `"my_module.configuration.cache"` instead of `"functools.cache"`.

Comment: @Samwise should I use the `start()` and `stop()` as well? didn't work with and without :(

Answer (score 6):

The `@cache` decorator adds a `cache_clear` attribute to the function that it decorates, so the simplest approach is to add this line to your test before you call the cached function:

```py
whitelist_sections.cache_clear()
```

If you find yourself doing this in a lot of your tests, you can make an auto-use fixture which always clears this cache.

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def clear_caches():
    whitelist_sections.cache_clear()
    other_cached_function.cache_clear()
```

Add it either in your test file or a suitably located `conftest.py` file to affect all tests recursively in that module.

Answer (score 1):

For the ones using `cachetools` package, you need to use the `cache_clear` method. For example if your function is something like this:

from cachetools.func import ttl_cache

```
@ttl_cache(maxsize=100, ttl=360)
def foo(x):
    # Do somthing with x
```

Then you can create a `fixture` with `pytest` like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def clear_cache():
    yield
    foo.cache_clear()
```